# Define kendoTooltip content Coordinates

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

Hello Everyone,
              I can display **kendoTooltip** contnet onmouseover. My concern is to display the tooltip content below the mouse pointer or would like to set **Co-ordintates**, so that there will be some space left between the text displayed and the button. Is there any way to do that.

Html tag

`<div id="AddnEditUserInfo" >`

ToolTip Code

```
$("#AddnEditUserInfo").kendoTooltip({
            filter:"input",
            autoHide: true,                 
            showOn: "mouseover",
            position: "right",
            width:100
        });
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/PYTEv/5/

css :

```
.k-tooltip{
    margin-top:5em;
}
```

You can just change css of the tooltip...

Comment: nice! thanks for that, pretty easy way to update all my tooltip's.

Answer (score 0):

Bit lazy before to try, tried changing **position:"pointer"** and it made the magic. Thanks